# Error using lib commons-dbcp2 (BasicDataSource class) in multi module java project

Tags: java, database, java-module

I want to use BasicDataSource for DB interconnection. In the "classic" java project (without modules) everything works correctly, but when i create multi module project some error occured at the compile time.

```
Error:(..) java: cannot access javax.management.MBeanRegistration
```

I have never met such errors before. Intersting then error occurs when i try to call any method of the BasicDataSource class

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setUsername("username"); //Error occurs here
```

Docs for lib says that:

> DBCP 2.7.0 compiles and runs under Java 8 only (JDBC 4.2)

But:

> DBCP 2.7.0 binaries should be used by applications running on Java 8 and above.

Ref: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

module-info.java:

```
module BusinessLogic {
    requires mysql.connector.java;
    requires java.sql;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;

   requires commons.dbcp2;
   requires commons.pool2;
   requires commons.logging;
}
```

So, i tried to use binaries but it didn't help, how can i avoid this problem?

Comment: `BasicDataSource` being in which library? And what version? What is the version of Java you're using with the new way? You should probably use the "java-modules" tag instead of "module".

Comment: I'am sorry BasicDataSource is not lib it's a class from lib (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). Lib-version 2.7.0. Java 12. Thanks for  "java-modules" comment.

Comment: So you're using [this commons-dbcp2 jar file](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2/2.7.0)? I'm trying to isolate what I need to do it create the same situation.

Comment: Yes, i am using it

Comment: I will send ref to git-rep with demo in 7 mins.

Comment: I think it's better if the information is in the Question itself. Then someone can reproduce it even if a link goes dead. If all that I need to know is one class and the library, then I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: Oh, i find the solution, thank you very much! It's necessary to specify one more dependency in module-info "requires java.management;".

Comment: Can i give star or something like that for help? (i don't see any buttons for it).

Comment: No, it's not possible. Then I have to post an Answer to your Question. But I did not know the answer. You found it yourself :)

Comment: Ok, then thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: It's necessary to specify one more dependency in module-info:

`requires java.management;`

or delete module-info.

module-info.java:

```
    module DBModule{
        requires mysql.connector.java;
        requires java.sql;
        requires commons.dbcp2;
        requires java.management;
    }
```